# Is there a situation where you shouldn't omit the article (a, the) in lyrics?

Tags: poetry, lyrics

Is there a situation where you shouldn't omit the article (a, the) in lyrics? Sometimes, you have 1 syllable you want to remove on a line, so you remove a or the, but sometimes doing so modifies the meaning or make it more vague.

> I have a big castle
>
> Made of blue marble
>
> Atop the blue sea

In this particular case, it sounds extremely weird.

> I have big castle
>
> Made of blue marble
>
> Atop blue sea

But I can't tell when to remove an article and when to keep it, because there aren't clear-cut conventions or rules.

Comment: I don't see why the rules would be different for lyrics than for prose. If you wouldn't omit the article in prose, I wouldn't omit it in lyrics.  Maybe alternate ways to reduce syllables are a better option. _"I've a big castle / made of blue marble / on the blue sea"_ Although, to be honest, having a syllable more or less doesn't always matter.

Comment: It will depend on what effect you want to give and what the context of the lyric is. If it's from the point of view of a small child, a robot, a foreigner, etc, it might sound ok; and if it's in a very stylised form, it might work to not use full sentences; but if you're going for other styles, e.g. a conversational tone or for something in elevated "poetic" diction, then it could be very odd to randomly miss out words.